# Linux makes tabs when copying and pasting code

Tags: ubuntu, vim, sublime-text

I use Linux Ubuntu for competitive programming, it's pretty good, but when I copy and paste my c++ code to submit it, it automatically adds tabs to my submission code at the beginning of some lines.

Does exist some way to fix it?

Because on MS-windows it's not problem with this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome, you tagged the question with `sublime` and `vim`, but they are not mentioned in the question. Could you explain it with more detail? From where are you copying the code and paste where?

Comment: When I submit my code from sublime text or vim to codeforces, or copying code from there and pasting in my editor

Comment: That's excellent news: it's not changing the content of your paste text

Comment: Yeah, but it's kinda anoying, I want to fix that.

Comment: [Its seem like a recurrent issue](https://www.google.com/?q=codeforces+code+spaces+tabs).

Comment: Put fixes is the question (not comments).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `vim` and the `Sublime Text` editors are configurable on whether they use spaces or tabs for indenting and whether they convert existing tabs to spaces (or vice versa) or not.

For `vim`, see [this question on vi & vim StackExchange.](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4141/9557) Basically, if you always want spaces instead of tabs, add `set expandtab` to your `~/.vimrc` file. If you want to convert existing tabs to spaces, type `:retab` when in command mode.

For Sublime Text, [see this part of its reference documentation](https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/settings.html#global-settings). Basically, you probably want to set `detect_indentation` to `false` to prevent Sublime from attempting to adapt to the existing practice within each file you load, then set `tab_size`, `use_tab_stops` `translate_tabs_to_spaces`, `auto_indent` and `trim_automatic_white_space` according to your preferences.